# Swiper.js Nested slider jumps child first & last slides on fast mousewheel

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

I have a vertical slider, where slide 2 is a nested vertical slider. On first slide, if you do slow mousewheel down, it takes you to 1st slide of nested slider. But if you repeat the same with fast mousewheel, you'll notice the first nested slide gets skipped. Same happens if you mousewheel up from slide 3.

Please check the codepen for more details.
https://codepen.io/jazzbotdev/pen/wvdoLzE

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-main">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Main 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-inner">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Inner Slide 1</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Inner Slide 2</div>
<!--                     <div class="swiper-slide">Inner Slide 3</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Inner Slide 4</div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">Inner Slide 5</div> -->
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-inner"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Main 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Main 4</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-main"></div>
</div>
```

```
var swiperH = new Swiper('.swiper-container-main', {
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-main',
    },
    paginationClickable: true,
    direction: 'vertical',
    spaceBetween: 50,
    mousewheel: {
      invert: false,
    },
    mousewheelForceToAxis: true,
    freeMode: false,
    mousewheelForceToAxis: false,
    mousewheelSensitivity: 0.5,
    freeModeMomentum: true,
    freeModeMomentumRatio: 10,
    freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0.01,
    freeModeSticky: false
});
var swiperV = new Swiper('.swiper-container-inner', {
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-inner',
    },
    paginationClickable: true,
    direction: 'vertical',
    spaceBetween: 50,
    nested: true,
    mousewheel: {
      invert: false,
    },
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEffect: {
      crossFade: true
    },
    mousewheelForceToAxis: true,
    freeMode: false,
    mousewheelForceToAxis: false,
    mousewheelSensitivity: 0.5,
    freeModeMomentum: true,
    freeModeMomentumRatio: 10,
    freeModeMinimumVelocity: 0.01,
    freeModeSticky: false
});
```

Comment: Any help from anyone?

Comment: Anyone please????